# Train a Neural Network with data sorted by relevance

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, classification

I have a dataset of pictures of a certain skin rash, which is sorted by doctors according to their prediction of how likely a certain rash is a "lyme disease". So the dataset consists of folders "50-70%", "70-80%", "80-90%", "90-100%". For example, in "90-100%" folder lie pictures which are most likely to be "lyme disease" and so on.

I want to use all of this data, but I wonder how to tell the Neural Network that pictures in this folder are certainly "lyme disease", and in other folder - less likely. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kamil, It totally depends on your requirement,

1)If you just wanted your model to know "lyme disease" or "not lyme disease"

you can set a limit, like anything above 80% is lyme and below is not lyme

so you can classify all the images with below 80% to have output of 0 and all the images above 80% to have output of 1

2)If you want your model to be more detailed, like different levels, you can do this way

"90-100%" -- has lyme                   [1,0,0,0]

"80-90%"  -- at high risk               [0,1,0,0]

"70-80%"  -- no risk                    [0,0,1,0]

"50-70%   -- no lyme                    [0,0,0,1]

and correspondingly you can have categorical outputs

Comment: So in (2) you mean to do multi classification instead of binary?

Answer (score 0):

Keras has the `ImageDataGenerator` class that is capable of loading images that are sorted in directories by their class. You have to create such an object and can then use the `.flow_from_directory(directory)` method.

Comment: Question is not in how to classify multiple classes. I have dataset which corresponds to one class, but with different certainty. So it should be binary classification "lyme disease" or "not lyme disease"

Comment: As I understood it, you have those pictures labeled by the likeliness of being that disease and want to train a NN to classify to what class a picture belongs. Am I right?

Comment: exactly. I want to train a NN which will be able to classify if it is that disease or it is not.